# Can I fit a 32-622 tire on a 32-630 rim?

Tags: tire, rims, size

Can I fit a 32-622 tire on a 32-630 rim?
The tire diameter is 8 mm smaller than the rim, so it's going to be tight - but will it fit with some extra force, and might there be any other problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You would need to stretch the tire circumference by 25 mm for it to fit. If the tire has steel beads (cables at the edges) stretching them is theoretically if not practically possible but the rest of the tire structure is fabric that does not stretch.

Comment: They are right that the diameter needs to stretch by 8mm. The 622 is the bead seat diameter. It's the circumference which needs to stretch by 25mm.

You're right that there is no chance of doing that.

(The rubber and fabric will stretch further under the same force than a wire or kevlar bead, but it will tear before you stretch it far enough. But you won't stretch the bead that far anyway. And if you could, it would collapse the wheel once it was on.)

Comment: Oops. I'm editing the answer text. But the point is was that steel survives plastic deformation, kevlar and and nylon or cotton not so much.

Comment: Technically the OP needs a 27" tire, 622 by today's standards is 29" so it will be much bigger by my logic not 8mm smaller

Comment: Thank you all! I found an old 622 tire laying around so I tried to put it on the 630 rim just to test, and I can confirm that it was impossible for me to get it on there with extra force (and I don't give up easily)... The answer to my question is NO :-)

Comment: @DanK Inch tire sizes refer to nominal tire diameters. "27 inch" is the nominal diameter of a road tire on a 630mm rim. "29 inch' means the nominal diameter of a fat MTB tire on a 622mm rim.

Comment: Personal logic is often different from facts.